# Can you use "Drop table ......." in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am creating a report which drops the table if it exists at the beginning and inserts the data that is needed.

The SQl runs smoothly in SQL Server Management Studio with no issues but when I place it into SSRS to create a report, it is saying that the synax is wrong.

I think I might need to do this as a stored procedure but I wanted to make sure that I have not missed anything first.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't drop/recreate tables in reports. But if you do - definitely use SP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the code in a Stored procedure, and use temporary tables or table variables rather.

Have a look at

[CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

> Temporary Tables
>
> You can create local and global temporary tables.
>   Local temporary tables are visible only in the current session, and
>   global temporary tables are visible to all sessions. Temporary tables
>   cannot be partitioned.
>
> Prefix local temporary table names with single number sign
>   (#table_name), and prefix global temporary table names with a double
>   number sign (##table_name).
>
> SQL statements reference the temporary table by using the value
>   specified for table_name in the CREATE TABLE statement

Also have a look at

[DECLARE @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx)

> @table_variable_name
>
> Is the name of a variable of type table. Variable names must begin
>   with an at (@) sign and conform to the rules for identifiers.
>
> Defines the table data type. The table declaration includes column
>   definitions, names, data types, and constraints. The only constraint
>   types allowed are PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, NULL, and CHECK. An alias data
>   type cannot be used as a column scalar data type if a rule or default
>   definition is bound to the type.
>
> is a subset of information used to define a
>   table in CREATE TABLE. Elements and essential definitions are included
>   here. For more information, see CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL).

Comment: Hi @astander, Thank you for replying. I am currently using local temporary tables to do this, but it takes 3 minutes to run which is ok, but the report has 2-sub reports that also takes 3 minutes as they are loading the data again which the main report is depent on. If I used a global Temp table would the sub reports be able to run off of the main reports temp table?